# Video tags not showing on the page

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm having trouble getting my video tags to show up on the page.

I know I've referenced them correctly because if I go to localhost:5000/vid/clip1.mp4 (live link:http://blue-goji.herokuapp.com/vid/clip1.mp4) it shows video controls but it wont play anything.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

relevant HTML:

```
<div class='container' id='video-grid'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <video class='grid-vid' src='vid/clip1.mp4'>Not Supported</video>
    </div> <!-- wrapper -->
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <video class='grid-vid' src='vid/clip2.mp4'>Not Supported</video>
    </div> <!-- wrapper -->
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <video class='grid-vid' src='vid/clip2.mp4'>Not Supported</video>
    </div> <!-- wrapper -->
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <video class='grid-vid' src='vid/clip3.mp4'>Not Supported</video>
    </div> <!-- wrapper -->
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <video class='grid-vid' src='vid/clip4.mp4'>Not Supported</video>
    </div> <!-- wrapper -->
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <video class='grid-vid' src='vid/clip4.mp4'>Not Supported</video>
    </div> <!-- wrapper -->
</div> <!-- container -->
```

live link: 
http://blue-goji.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I went to the live link and was able to see the video tags in the DOM.

Comment: Sorry maybe i meant not showing up on the page. If inspect the empty white area under the nav bar I can see the video tags shown in the source/DOM. but they aren't showing up on the page... there is just a big white space where they should go.

Comment: I went into the inspector and replaced the src attribute with a video link from an external site and the element became visible, the issue seems to be with the server or the video.

Comment: The video you’re supplying doesnt work: http://blue-goji.herokuapp.com/vid/clip1.mp4

Answer (score 1):

The video element does show up on the page, it just blends in with the background because it is the same color. There is an issue with either the video file or the server hosting it.

To make it clearer to the user that there is going to be additional content while the video is still loading or there is an error like in this case you can add a different background to the video element:

```
video {
    background: gray;
}
```